# jsPlumb - unable to connect source to target

Tags: connection, jsplumb

This is the code that executes on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jsPlumb.importDefaults({
            Connector: ["Bezier", { curviness: 3 }],
            PaintStyle: { strokeStyle: "#4682B4", lineWidth: 4 },
            EndpointStyle: { radius: 10, fillStyle: "#4682B4" },                
            Anchors: ["BottomCenter"]
        });
        jsPlumb.setContainer($("#graph"));

        connections.forEach(function(element) {
            jsPlumb.connect({source: element.source, target: element.target});
        });
    });
```

Before I attempt the connections on the last line above I create divs in code:

```
function createDiv(id, innerHTML, width, height, left, top, cssclass) {
        var div = $("<div/>");

        if (cssclass)
            $(div).text(innerHTML);
        else
            $(div).append(innerHTML);

        $("#graph").append(
            $(div)
                .attr("id", id)
                .addClass(cssclass)
                .css({top: top, left: left, cursor: "move"})                    
                .width(width ? width : 180)
                .height(height ? height : 25)
        );

        jsPlumb.draggable($("#" + id));
    }
```

The error I keep getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" on the line that I try to connect. What am I missing?

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jsPlumb-2.0.6-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">....</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="expression"></div> 
    <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```